# Iterating over words across vector of strings and applying change to single word

Tags: r, string, list, apply, sapply

Given string:

```
words <- c("fauuucet water", "tap water")
```

I would like to apply `toupper` function to all words that contain **`u`**.

#### Desired results

```
res <- c("FAUUCET water", "tap water")
```

## Function

```
change_u_case <- function(str) {
    sapply(
        X = str,
        FUN = function(search_term) {
            sapply(
                X = strsplit(search_term, split = "\\s", perl = TRUE),
                FUN = function(word) {
                    if (grepl(pattern = "u", x = word)) {
                        toupper(word)
                    }
                }
                ,
                USE.NAMES = FALSE
            )
        },
        USE.NAMES = FALSE
    )
}
```

### Tests

```
change_u_case(words) -> tst_res
words
tst_res
unlist(tst_res)
```

---

## Notes

- In particular, I'm interested whether solution using single [`rapply`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rapply.html) call could be build
- [`rlist::list.iter`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rlist/versions/0.4.6.1/topics/list.iter) approach would be also interesting
- The selection of words containing **u** character is an example, in practice I would be looking to apply various conditions reflecting length and so on

Comment: @Sotos Thanks for the contribution. It works fine; personally I was thinking if it would be possible to not execute twice `i[grepl('u', i)]` and build it as `function(word) {if/do}`. If nothing neater appears I would be happy to accept your solution if you care to provide as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `stringi`-based solution:

```
library(stringi);
sapply(stri_extract_all_words(words),
    function(w) paste(ifelse(stri_detect(w, regex = "u"), toupper(w), w), collapse = " "))
#[1] "FAUUUCET water" "tap water"
```

Comment: So far my favourite solution as it allows for flexibility in terms of identifying words and applying transformations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a single `sapply` call, i.e.

```
sapply(strsplit(words, ' '), function(i) {i1 <- grepl('u', i); 
                                         i[i1] <- toupper(i[i1]); 
                                         paste0(i, collapse = ' ')
                                         })
#[1] "FAUUUCET water" "tap water"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `stringr`:

```
str_replace_all(words, '\\w*u\\w*', toupper)
# [1] "FAUUUCET water" "tap water"
```

More examples:

```
str_replace_all(c('Upset', 'day day up'), '\\w*u\\w*', toupper)
# [1] "Upset"      "day day UP"
```